# How to test a server side function in Meteor without including it in global namespace

Tags: meteor, mocha-web-velocity

In my server side file I have two functions defined for which I want to write test cases which are residing in a file in tests directory.

~PRJ_DIR/server/file1.coffee

```
calcSha1Hash = (params) ->
    .... logic...
anotherFunc = () ->
    ..somelogic..
    x = calcSha1Hash(params)
```

~PRJ_DIR/tests/server/file1.coffee

```
MochaWeb?.testOnly () ->
  describe.only("Hash generation.  ", () ->
    it(" calcSha1Hash returns Hash.", (dn) ->
      dataDict = {email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'}
      hash = calcSha1Hash (dataDict)
      chai.assert.isDefined(hash)
      dn()
    )
  )
```

How is it possible to call the server side func(calcSha1Hash) in my test case in Meteor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a meteor-specific way to do this, you can implement the solution from [How to Unit Test Private Functions in JavaScript](http://philipwalton.com/articles/how-to-unit-test-private-functions-in-javascript/)

You will need to have a single global variable (something like `TestAPI`).  Then add your functions to it inside of a closure so you can access them from anywhere.

Here's an example from the article:

```js
var myModule = (function() {

  function foo() {
    // private function `foo` inside closure
    return "foo"
  }

  var api = {
    bar: function() {
      // public function `bar` returned from closure
      return "bar"
    }
  }

  /* test-code */
  api._foo = foo
  /* end-test-code */

  return api
}())
```

Someone might have something better, but that's a start.